# Compare two ways of declaring an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

```
int buf1[] = {0,0,0,0,0};

int* buf2 = new int[5]; //assume every element is initialzed to 0 as well
```

The only difference I can think of is buf1 is a reference to the array while buf2 is a pointer pointing to the array. In other words, buf1 always refers to the array while buf2 can point to other places as well.

Besides the mentioned one, is there any other difference between the two ways of declaring(and initializing an array)?

Comment: Why do you assume every element is initialized in the `new` case?

Comment: @FredLarson I just omitted the initialization steps so as to save some space here.

Comment: Whilst it's specifically for C, this may be of some use: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @Polynomial Very helpful. Solved my confusion!

Comment: Just a note, as of the 2003 version of c++. If you want your second example to be 0 initialized, you can write: `int* buf2 = new int[5]();`

Comment: @EvanTeran Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`buf1` is an automatic object (or static if it's in the global scope); `*buf2` is a dynamic object. That is, the lifetime of `buf1` is controlled automatically, while the lifetime of `*buf2` is yours to manage. (`buf2` lives until you say something like `delete[] buf2;`.)

The initializers are also different; `buf1` is brace-initialized, while `*buf2` is default-initialized (i.e. its `int` elements are uninitialized).

Comment: +1:  Teh fact that `buf1` is automatic while `buf2` is dynamic is by far the most important difference here.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case:

- automatic (in function scope) or static (in namespace scope) allocation is used
- you have initialized the values to all zeros

In the second case:

- dynamic allocation is used (and you will have to `delete []` later)
- The array is uninitialized

Answer (score 2):

```
int buf1[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

This gives *automatic* storage, if it's in a block, or *static* storage if it's in a namespace. In the first case, it will last until the program leaves the block it's declared inside; in the second, it lasts until the program exits.

```
int* buf2 = new int[5];
```

This creates the array dynamically; you have control over its lifetime, and it lasts until you delete it (`delete [] buf2`). If you don't delete it, then there is a memory leak, which is something you should avoid. To ensure that dynamic objects get deleted correctly, it's better not to manage them directly with a raw pointer, but should use a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) class, such as a smart pointer or a container, to manage it for you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, whether or not there's a memory leak depends on your implementation of `::operator new()` (e.g. it could allocate from a pool that you clean up properly). What you do always have is a "lifetime leak".

Answer (score 1):

If you declare int buf1[] = {0,0,0,0,0}; in function after you exit from it the array will be destroyed. In the second case you have to manually delete the array after you finish using it like this delete [] buf2, but this way it won't be destroyed automatically, so you can use it everywhere until you delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact you have to clean (delete) your second version?  And that the first and second versions will be allocated in different areas of RAM?  And that the first may take up ever so slightly more executable space if those 0s are stored instead of generated?  Or that  the second version will even clear that RAM to 0 for you, which I don't believe it will.

They are very different.